# Is there a way to share data between an abstract class and it's implementation classes without using companion object in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, abstract-class

I have a class called `Animal` which is an abstract class.

```
abstract class Animal {

 protected var totalAnimals = 0

 fun provideTotalAnimals(totalAnimals: Int) {
  this.totalAnimals = totalAnimals
 }

}
```

Now there is another class that is extending `Animal` says a `Dog`

```
class Dog: Animal() {
 
 fun printTotalDogsAndAnimals(totalDogs: Int) {
  val totalAnimals = totalDogs + totalAnimals 
  println("Total Animals: $totalAnimals")
 }
}
```

Since I'm extending the `Animal` class I'm able to get hold of the `totalAnimals`. But, the problem is that `totalAnimals` will be always 0 no matter what. I fixed this by putting the `totalAnimals` inside a companion object in the `Animal` class. But, I would like to know is there a better way to share the data from an abstract class and its implementation classes without using a companion object. A better way to design my classes is what I'm looking at.

Comment: why wouldn't it be zero ? you're not changing it ? `val totalAnimals` is declaring a new variable, you're not pointing to the same thing as what you have in your abstract class, you could have `val foo` in your abstract class and `val bar` in your `Dog` class essentially

Answer (score 0):

You should override abstract class's function to set totalAnimals value. In your case, you are adding some value to 0 and printing it.